# Laravel ORM get records in-between dates?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have tasks table along with date columns 'reminder date' and 'due date'. I need to get all tasks in between those days referencing today. I have little knowledge in query so ORM will be better.

I tried,

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$availTasks = Task::whereRaw($today.' between rem_date and due_date')->get();
echo ($availTasks);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to make your date string used correctly it should be:

```
$availTasks = Task::whereRaw('? between rem_date and due_date', [$today])->get();
```

if your `rem_date` and `due_date` columns are `DATE` type it should work. However if they are `DATETIME` type it won't work. You should use then:

```
$availTasks = Task::whereRaw('? between DATE(rem_date) and DATE(due_date)', [$today])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a compound where using a closure:

```
$dateToday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query = Task::where(function ($query) use ($dateToday){
    $query->where('rem_date', '>=', $dateToday);
    $query->where('due_date', '<', $dateToday);
});
echo $query->get();
```

Also when using whereRaw you should always bind your parameters as it can become an injection vector. I know that the parameter is just the date in your case, but it's just good practice. See mr. Nabiałek answer about this.

Comment: Upvote, also using comparison operators allows DB's like MySQL to use date indexes